# My Snowflake UI session does NOT expire after FOUR hours of inactivity. How can I solve this issue?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE is FALSE, in spite of it, my Snowflake UI session does NOT expire after FOUR hours of inactivity. I am looking for solution for UI, How can this issue be fixed? I appreciate your help.
Thank you in advance.
RV

Comment: CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE is not applicable to Snowflake UI, only to JDBC, ODBC, Python, Node.js. UI works differently and nowadays will be terminated after 4 hours with a new change bundle (previous behavior was 2 weeks rather than 4 hours).

Answer (score 1):

Guess, the bundle might be disabled for the account:

```
SELECT SYSTEM$BEHAVIOR_CHANGE_BUNDLE_STATUS('2021_08');
```

Related: [New Web Interface: Client Session Limited to 4 Hours of Inactivity](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Client-Session-Limited-to-4-Hours-of-Inactivity-Pending)